# HTML input time max at midnight

Tags: html, validation, input, time

I am trying to setup a input field like

```
<input type="time" id="end" step="1800" min="10:00" max="24:00">
```

The problem is it seems like 24:00 is not valid format for "Midnight". Now I am wondering which would be valid.

Tank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. To me the time for midnight is 00:00 (the first hour of the next day). The last second of a day is 23:59:59.

Comment: To go into detail:
I have a form where I want so create an event. This event can end somewhere between 10:00 and midnight (24:00). If I set max to 23:59:59 I won't be able to select the midnight time. If I set 24:00 the input can be also set to times like 06:30 which is not my goal.

Comment: Ok. So I think you have to validate the time with javascript and not HTML5 for 2 reasons : type="time" is not supported in Firefox, or Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions, and you will be able to validate the time with your own regex :)

Comment: I was afraight to get answer like this, but as long as noone will provide a solution I think regex is the way I will go. Thank you.